# What is the name for this kind of graph that shows mean and shading?

Tags: data-visualization, dispersion

What is the name for this kind of graph?

[image: Graph showing temporal evolution of data by means of a mean (average line) and shading to show dispersion around the mean]

For those unable to view the image, it shows the temporal evolution of a variable by means of a mean trend line, with dispersion indicated by shading (density) around the mean line. I would like to look into this for plotting temporal data as to my mind it gives a better indication of dispersion than e.g. a graph showing mean line plus standard deviation.

Comment: this guy provide here (http://www.nicebread.de/visually-weighted-watercolor-plots-new-variants-please-vote/) some graphs, and he name it watercolor plots; he provide also some R code for that.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "dispersion": is it a running estimate of a measure of dispersion, like standard deviation, or could it be the *actual data*?

Comment: @whuber, I think it's the actual data. But the reason for showing it (I imagine) is to tell how the data is dispersed around the mean (which a single number like stdev can't give you)

Comment: A running SD (or any running estimate of dispersion) *would* tell you how the data are dispersed. But since you think the plot actually shows the data, we now know how to interpret your question: you are asking for the name of a time-series plot over which a smooth has been superimposed.  But why ask for a name?  What question does that actually answer?